# Implementing a Queue in a Circular Array

Tags: arrays, queue

Let's say I have an array of length 4 and I want to enqueue and dequeue some characters. What would happen if there is no enough "space" to add the next character of the operation?

For example:

**(1) Enqueue  the characters B, N, R in that order**

```
index 0   index 1    index 2   index 3  --------Here front index = 0 and size = 3
 B           N          R
```

**(2)Dequeue two characters**

```
index 0   index 1    index 2   index 3  ------Now the front index = 2 and size = 1
                       R
```

**(3) Enqueue characters P, O, A, W in that order**

```
index 0   index 1    index 2   index 3  
 O          A          R         P
```

So my question is: why would happen to character W if there  is no more space left to "use"?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy answer, this is the downside of a circular buffer. Depending on the implementation there are various things you could do to manage this situation:

1) Block the call and wait for there to be space (assuming a multithreaded environment)

2) Return some sort of error code or throw an exception

3) Resize the buffer and update the two pointers (this would be an expensive operation compared to add/delete)